# Chart.js doughnut canvas padding

Tags: css, angular, chart.js

I currently have a canvas containing a chart.js doughnut inside a div that looks like this:

[image]

The canvas has a red background color for visibility. Right now, the chart is centered in the canvas with extra padding on its sides. I'd like the chart to fill the entirety of the canvas so that there is no padding at all, so that the canvas can be aligned similarly to the "CPU" word above. Is there some option in chart.js for this?

Here's the html:

```
<p class="header">CPU</p>
<div class="doughnut-canvas-container">
   <canvas id="doughnut-canvas" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>          
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.header {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: Verdana;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.doughnut-canvas-container {
    width: 30%;
}

#doughnut-canvas {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your code for creating the chart it's only possible to guess at what the problem might be.

Generally speaking if you disable the `legend` and the `title` the chart should fill to the edge of the canvas, like so:

```js
new Chart(
  document.getElementById('doughnut-canvas'),
  {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        data: [2, 1],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      title: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}
.header {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: Verdana;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.doughnut-canvas-container {
  width: 30%;
}

#doughnut-canvas {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<p class="header">CPU</p>
<div class="doughnut-canvas-container">
  <canvas id="doughnut-canvas" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I know this was asked a long time ago. But im having the same issue. The answer you gave has the same issue as he was talking about. The graph does NOT stretch to the edge of the canvas width.

Comment: @littlevahn I don’t have access to a computer right now to check but I’m fairly sure the example in my answer shows a chart that fills to the top and bottom. Have you run it? And which browser are you using?

Comment: Ah, ok i misread his initial question. I was thinking he was trying to fill on the sides. Fill based on width

Comment: Ok. Only option there is to make the canvas a square. E.g. 300x300px.